# How can I get the RInside example sandboxed_server to work on OS X Yosemite?

Tags: macos, callback, rcpp, rinside

I'm having trouble getting the sandboxed_server example from RInside/examples/sandboxed_server working on xcode. I have OS X Yosemite 10.10.1.

I get the following error:

```
clang++ server/rinsideserver.o common/binarystream.o datatypes/bar.o datatypes/foo.o example_server.o   -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -llzma -lz -licucore -lm -liconv  -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRblas -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRlapack  /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/RInside/lib/libRInside.a -o example_server
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"RInside::set_callbacks(Callbacks*)", referenced from:
  _main in example_server.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [example_server] Error 1
Command /usr/bin/make failed with exit code 2
```

I have not been able to get any example that uses callbacks to work. Examples (from standard examples) that don't use callbacks do work.

I've uncommented #define RINSIDE_CALLBACKS in RInsideConfig.h. I've reinstalled the source files through R/CRAN from source- as was suggested on another post.

I did modify the code in sandboxed_server to get CLOCK_MONOTONIC to work on mac- but nothing other than that.

I'd really like to get this example working. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is contributed code within the package so your best bet may be to contact its author.